# Highcharts map: detect zoom or pan

Tags: highcharts

I have a map and want to detect whenever it is zoomed or panned by the user. I understand that best way to do this would seem to be with the *afterSetExtremes* event.
I'm using buttons to zoom but the user can double click to zoom in too and pan.

The event doesn't seem to fire though but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or if there is another event I should be using to achieve this. Here's a JSFiddle which is based on one of the Highmaps demos, just with the event added:

https://jsfiddle.net/nbymstxe/

What am I doing wrong?

```
Highcharts.getJSON('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highcharts/highcharts@v7.0.0/samples/data/world-population-density.json', function (data) {

// Prevent logarithmic errors in color calulcation
data.forEach(function (p) {
    p.value = (p.value < 1 ? 1 : p.value);
});

// Initialize the chart
Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
    chart: {
        map: 'custom/world'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Zoom in on country by double click'
    },

    mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        enableDoubleClickZoomTo: true
    },

    colorAxis: {
        min: 1,
        max: 1000,
        type: 'logarithmic'
    },
     xAxis: {
        events: {
         afterSetExtremes() {
         console.log("Extremes set");
          }
      },
   },
    series: [{
        data: data,
        joinBy: ['iso-a3', 'code3'],
        name: 'Population density',
        states: {
            hover: {
                color: '#a4edba'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '/km²'
        }
    }]
});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can use the `render` callback to detect when user has zoomed or panned the chart.

```
  events: {
    render() {
       console.log(this.mapView)
    }
  }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zpn5goaj/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. It fires a lot! I was really hoping for something that would fire only when a zoom or pan had been completed. That was why I was drawn to the afterSetExtremes event. Thanks anyway — it's helpful.